# Meaning of よりまし in バンパー外すよりまし

Tags: meaning, slang, kansai-ben

A friend posted on a social network a picture of his Subaru car's bumper after an minor accident, and got this comment:

> 大丈夫！バンパー外す**より**まし！笑

I guess it means

> *No problem! Removing the bumper will make it look better! lol*

But what is the exact meaning of よりまし in this sentence?

It's in Kansai if that matters.

Comment: Do you realize that よりまし should be parsed as より + まし?

Comment: @Earthliŋ: I did not realize that sorry :-/

Answer (score 6):

**Edit.** (Thanks to naruto for pointing out the correct translation.)

> 大丈夫！バンパー外すよりまし！笑
>   No problem! Better than missing the bumper! lol

よりまし is より ("than") + まし ("better"). I don't quite know why, but you seem to get the opposite meaning.

Comment: 多分ですが、この「外す」は「取り外す(remove)」ではなくて「命中しない(fail to hit)」の意味じゃないですかね。「バンパーに当たらない（バンパー以外の場所に当たってしまう）よりまし」と解釈するのが自然だと思います。

Comment: @naruto そうかもしれませんね。この回答の解釈はバンパーを外したとしたら、他のパーツにも当たらないようなところで傷していない限り、解釈になりそうもないですね。narutoさんの回答をundeleteしてください。

Comment: いや、"外す"の解釈はoff-topicですので、こちらの回答が適切だと思います。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @naruto I will incorporate your comments into my answer, but please don't hesitate to post alternative answers, especially if they are more accurate than existing answers.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm starting to feel "(In terms of safety or appearance, driving this car with the damaged bumper is) better than without the bumper." is also possible interpretation. Although driving a bumper-less car is illegal and a strange idea, I can't deny some car geeks think that way...

Comment: @naruto Maybe the OP will enlighten us with a picture.

Answer (score 1):

```
外す           　より　            マシ
take off    rather than         better
```

Depending on the context (i.e. previous comments), I'd guess the meaning is

"It still looks better than without the bumper"